# colnames as vector if colsums is > 0

Tags: r, col

Trying to get the colnames of columns which totals are > 0.  I have tried

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) any(x > 0))]
```

but this gives me the actual numeric value.  I then tried

```
names(df)[colSums(df)>0]
```

but received a NULL.  Here is an example of my df where I would expect the output of "SRR960396" and "SRR960403".

```
> dput(df)
structure(c(14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0), dim = 4:3, dimnames = list(
    c("27b1da20c7a5364614a540521d5e38c0", "bd60888ac07bff9651845c6f6aca4fa8", 
    "e7474b1fd688aa54814538b69a56d202", "85907e71eb899b7edce9bf8d23746413"
    ), c("SRR960396", "SRR960402", "SRR960403")))
```

Comment: It looks like your `df` is an array, not a data.frame. Use `colnames(df)[colSums(df)>0]` instead of just `names()`. You can also try something like `names(Filter(function(x) x>0, colSums(df)))`

Comment: Code golf on @MrFlick's filter: `names(Filter(c, colSums(df)))`. In this case, `Filter` accepts something that is "true-like", which means `0` is false, non-zero is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be aware that `df` is NOT a `data.frame` but a `matrix`, i.e.,

```
> class(df)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

so `colnames(df)`, instead of `names`, should be used to fetch the column names.

---

A workaround is using `colSums` + `which` to locate the columns that have positive values, e.g.,

```
> names(which(colSums(df > 0) > 0))
[1] "SRR960396" "SRR960403"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using your approach:

```
colnames(df)[apply(df, 2, function(x) any(x > 0))]
[1] "SRR960396" "SRR960403"
```

Another alternative:

```
colnames(df)[which(df>0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]]
[1] "SRR960396" "SRR960403"
```